# Change inline code background formatting

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Everyone knows that [inline code blocks are dangerous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back).

They attract bad edits at a blistering pace and even when used *appropriately* `they` `look` **`ugly` `as` `hell`**. So what do we do, us aesthetes and artists, whose eyes and minds are burned by such a sight and we who feel wronged by such cruelty? Where is the light?

Currently, these blocks have a background colour `#eee`. This, you may know from doing base-16 arithmetic all day, is obviously

```
rgba(238, 238, 238, 1.0)
```

I propose it becomes

```
rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5)
```

or 50% transparent. (Alternatively, there are several other styles available to try.)

Here's a **now-updated** script to test it out with:

```
head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
head.appendChild(style);

keys = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
forceColour = 'code { background: rgba(238, 238, 238, {colour}) !important; }';

altStyle = [
    "pre code {",
    "    font-size: 14px !important;",
    "    padding: 1px 5px;",
    "    border: none;",
    "    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);",
    "    /* border-radius: initial; */",
    "    padding: 0;",
    "}",
    "",
    "code {",
    "    white-space: pre-wrap;",
    "    /* padding: 1px 5px; */",
    "    font-size: 12px;",
    "    box-sizing: border-box;",
    "    /* margin: 0; */",
    "    border: 1px solid {color};",
    "    background-color: #f8f8f8;",
    "    border-radius: 3px;",
    "    padding-left: 3px;",
    "    padding-right: 3px;",
    "}",
].join("\n");
altColours = {};
altColours["a"] = "#ddd";
altColours["s"] = "#eee";
altColours["d"] = "#f8f8f8";

document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

    if (key in altColours) {
        style.innerHTML = altStyle.replace("{color}", altColours[key]);
    }

    index = keys.indexOf(key);
    if (index > -1) {
        style.innerHTML = forceColour.replace("{colour}", index/(keys.length-1));
    }
};
```

Just paste it into whatever console your browser has and press:

```
1: No background
2: 25% opacity
3: 50% opacity (the best!)
4: 75% opacity
5: fully opaque (like always)
```

Or some variants using CSS stolen from Cupcake:

```
a: Github-Style
s: Github-Style with lighter lines
d: Github-Style with no visible border
```

[The first link I gave is a good place to test it on.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back)

If you still aren't convinced, here's a large image ([direct link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTGh8.png)):

[image: A comparison of aesthetic styles]

Comment: The GitHub styling you gave needs work (no left and right padding, for example, although I think GitHub actually uses pseudo-elements for that instead of padding), but already I think it's a big improvement over the existing styling, definitely improved readability.

Comment: [Painting the bikeshed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality).

Comment: Regarding your GitHub alternative S and D styles, the closer you get to D, the more it becomes like how Stack Overflow styles inline code blocks, which I don't really like all that much. The border that A uses gives the inline code more "pop", helping to distinguish it from plain text. When you essentially remove the border like in D, then it becomes harder to differentiate code from plain text, which I think reduces readability, instead of improving it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey perhaps, but then also "[Understanding code is by far the activity at which professional developers spend most of their time](http://blog.codinghorror.com/when-understanding-means-rewriting/)". If a particular styling (like a coding convention) can help me better understand pieces of code (or an answer on Stack Overflow), I think that's something worth considering.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Painting the bikeshed is fine as long as you spend the time to build it first. We're not yet at risk of being distracted from important activities due to this, which is the reason to be wary of bikeshedding.

Comment: *[totally missing the point]*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I still do, then. What point am I missing?

Comment: The only real difference I see between your version and the original is that yours makes code blocks harder to notice which is a little self-defeating.

Comment: I don't like either one of them because it introduces too much space between transitions between the normal and code style. In answers I often leave space characters out to overcome that, but that can affect word-wrapping negatively and the results are inconsistent with those from doing the same thing in comments.

Comment: @martineau Reducing the colour contrast doesn't change the spacing at all.

Comment: @Veedrac: True. I didn't phrase what I meant well. I don't like either one because neither addresses my dislike of the way spacing between transitions code and non-code appears.

Comment: I sometimes find myself wishing there were a means of highlighting that was somewhat less pronounced than backticks, but would nonetheless provide a clear visual distinction between "human"-relevant and machine-relevant concepts.  For example, I think it's nicer to talk about an `add` method than an "add" method, but it would be nice not to have the background-color highlighting in such cases.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I'd like to see inline styling the same way that GitHub style's theirs (screenshot from [Ruby on Rails on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails):

[image: Screenshot]

I find their style to be much more readable (maybe because the font-size is slightly smaller for inline code?). The inline code still "pops" out and is easily distinguishable from just plain text, but it does so in a way that doesn't cause the entire page to become too noisy and hard to read either.

### Mockup

Here is a mockup of what the styling would look like (before and after, [post tested on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/456814)):

[image: Before screenshot]

[image: After screenshot]

and here are the CSS rules to create it:

```css
pre code {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  /* border-radius: initial; */
  padding: 0;
}

code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* padding: 1px 5px; */
  font-size: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* margin: 0; */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
```

Note that some of those rules aren't the ***exact*** rules that GitHub uses, I had to make it work with Stack Overflow's existing CSS rules. It isn't perfect, but it's good enough, considering I didn't want to spend a lot of time trying to get the styling to be perfect.

Comment: Your CSS is now integrated into the script so many thanks. It's nice, although I prefer the less visually heavy style from my original suggestion.

Comment: @Veedrac great idea turning it into a JavaScript, by the way, that's a pretty genius way to demo a mockup.

Answer (score 5):

### No, please don't.

**Regarding using it for code:**

This would make inline code sample that's actually code harder to differentiate, and thus also make the whole post harder to read ... and the whole point of inline **code** sample is to use it for **code**. Code isn't English - your brain (well, okay, my brain) needs to make a little switch during processing when going from one to the other - having it clearly differentiated makes helps with that switch.

**Regarding using it for something other than code:**

Let's either fix the posts (through editing) or try to fix the behaviour (perhaps some combination of gentle notes, firm notes and bans), not make the behaviour a bit better (but not much better than before).

Or we could consider giving them something they could use instead, that they'd be happy with (no idea what). Personally I have no idea why they don't **just make things bold instead** - this highlights it enough already (italics to some extent as well, but sometimes *it's just kind of hard to spot*, which kind of defeats the purpose) (although the type of people using inline code sample to highlight things mostly highlight the wrong things anyway - bold would likely be just as bad).

Comment: I think it might be helpful to distinguish "complete" bits of code from "fragments" such as identifiers, function names, etc.  Having things like identifiers, keywords, etc. appear in a monospaced font is helpful, but applying the background color to each usage of an identifer can be a bit much.