# Is it possible to change the color of inline code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to change the color of some text on Stack Overflow? The contrast of phrases emphasized by backtick escapes doesn't show up well.

I would like to color them.

Comment: *"The contrast of phrases emphasized by backtick escapes doesn't show up well."* Don't use code markup for emphasis. Actually, don't use contrast for emphasis at all. Thankfully we try to maintain professional norms here and that included proper typography (i.e. not sprinkling different colors willy-nilly through the text).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change inline code background formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260554/456814).

Comment: For some questions, a white font on a white background would be useful:)

Comment: Restyle with custom style sheets in your browser.

Comment: @vfclists: There's nothing sarcastic about that comment, and I find it ironic that you think there is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But I might be guilty of superciliousness in the second degree. I admit my fault and throw myself on the mercy of the court.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't. If you want to emphasize words, you can use bold or italics. Also, backticks are for code and **not** for emphasizing phrases or words.

Comment: Is isn't preceding code by 4 spaces the way to highlight it? I am referring to things like program output, domain specific words like keywords, error messages etc. Lots of the time they are hard to distinguish from the surrounding words.

Comment: @vfclists If you want to emphasize error messages, then you can put that in a code block by preceding it by 4 spaces.

Comment: I prefer to use code blocks for multiline output only but keep single line messages in line with the normal text, otherwise when you have a number of them the text becomes too long.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Yes, of course, there is. Why do you think there is no way to do it?]

Comment: For the love of all that is good, no.

Comment: Out of all your ideas, this is the least impressive ;-)

Comment: @Payeli Could you tell me what my idea is the **most** impressive? Just curious.

Comment: The bounty distribution without rep, and the mod tag, it's a tie between them

Comment: You have a gift, which shouldn't be copied. Some things and people should be unique :-)

Comment: My eyes! The goggles! ... oh, you get the point.